# No items to review instructions

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

So I have been faithfully reviewing away on History SE. I came to the last one and reviewed it. The system then gave me this screen:

[image]

It says `There are no items for you to review.` It then goes on to give the guidelines for reviewing.

I closed the tab and then reopened it via the main review page. I then received the correct screen as shown here:

[image]

Comment: *Obviously*, you need to click one of those buttons! ;-)

Comment: LOL... but there are no shiny orange buttons!

Comment: Then, as the note says, `"You can also leave a comment on the answer..."`

Comment: Still no shiny orange buttons... :(

Comment: @Gaffi careful, if you click reccomend delete when there isn't a post to review it will delete all of stackexchange!

Comment: @Rory - effectively sending the internet into a spiralling black hole, dragging us with it

Comment: Has anyone been able to reproduce this?

Comment: @Luke I just reproduced it locally; it'll be fixed after our next deploy (sometime today).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good catch – this case was broken after a recent javascript refactoring. It's fixed now.